# how to match each line wrapped by start/end tag?

Tags: regex

I want to convent my blog from markdown to html. And, I used `[crayon lang="cpp"]...[/crayon]` to paste code. I wanted to get each line that wrapped by `[crayon][/crayon]`, and then add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. For example:

```
Some text

[crayon lang="bash"]
#!/bin/bash
[/crayon]

other text

[crayon lang="cpp"]
int main()
{
}
[/crayon]
```

I want it to be:

```
Some text

    #!/bin/bash

other text

    int main()
    {
    }
```

I don't know how to do it by `regex`. Could anyone help me?

Here is what I've tried:

- `\[crayon.*?\]([\d\D]*?)\[\/crayon\]` `\1` matches all lines wrapped by the `[crayon][/crayon]`, but I can't add spaces.
- `(?'st'\[crayon.*?\])^.*$(?'-st'\[/crayon\])` doesn't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (relatively) easy way would be to do it in two steps:

#### 1

Insert 4 spaces at the start of each line, but only lines *after* `'[crayon lang="..."]'` and *before* `'[/crayon]'`

```
pattern     : (?ms)^(?=(?:(?!\[crayon\b).)*\[/crayon])
replacement : '    ' (4 spaces)
```

#### 2

Remove all `'[crayon lang="..."]'` and `'[/crayon]'`

```
pattern     : \[/?crayon.*?][ \t]*(\r?\n|$)
replacement : '' (empty string)
```

A PHP demo:

```php
<?php

$text = 'Some text

[crayon lang="bash"]
#!/bin/bash
[/crayon]

other text

[crayon lang="cpp"]
int main()
{
}
[/crayon]';

$text = preg_replace('#^(?=(?:(?!\[crayon\b).)*\[/crayon])#ms', '    ', $text);

$text = preg_replace('#\[/?crayon.*?][ \t]*(\r?\n|$)#', '', $text);

echo "$text\n";

?>
```

which would print:

```
Some text

    #!/bin/bash

other text

    int main()
    {
    }
```

A quick explanation of the, perhaps terse regex `^(?=(?:(?!\[crayon\b).)*\[/crayon])`:

```
^                    # match the start of a line
(?=                  # start positive look ahead
  (?:                #   start group
    (?!\[crayon\b).  #     match any char as long as it doesn't have `[crayon` in front of it
  )*                 #   end group and repeatr it zero or more times
  \[/crayon]         #   match '[/crayon]'
)                    # end positive look ahead
```

In plain English that would read:

> match any start of a line, *only* if there's a `[/crayon]` ahead of this line-start, *and*  in between this line-start and `[/crayon]` there cannot be a `[crayon`.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. You can use it, if you think its ok.

```
1. Scan line by line:
    a. Look for \[crayon.+\] this pattern
    b. if you don't find this pattern then write the line as it present
    c. if you find this pattern then don't write anything and look for \[\/crayon\] this pattern
    d. until you find this pattern write every line by adding 4 spaces beginning of it.
    e. when you find (c) specified pattern then don't write anything and again start from (a)
```

Comment: aha, thx! that's a way to solve problem. actually, i've done it before asking the question. i asked this question just to learn regex.

Comment: different language have different ways to handle newline. i.e. python uses re.DOTALL, php uses \s end of regex. so, i think that is language specific.
Also, replace by 4 spaces. I have no idea to do it using only regex.

Answer (score -1):

How about `\[crayon.*?\]\n(.*\n)*?\[\/crayon\]\n`.  This way `\1` can capture each individual line.

Comment: Regex are typically defined for a single line. Using `\n` to simple regex won't help.